# npx does not look for latest version of package

Tags: node.js, npm, npx, npm-publish

I was making a simple npm package, I deleted the first version i.e, v0.1.0. So there is no v0.1.0 for my package. But I published later versions, with latest being v0.3.0. But when I execute `npx <package-name>`, it does not install latest version(v0.3.0). Instead it throws the following error.

[image: screenshot of error message]

But when I specify the version of the package (`npx <project-name>@v0.3.0`),it works.
So how can I make npx install latest version with being mentioned explicitly?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-flask

Answer (score 12):

This is how npx is designed to work. Basically it's always best to run npx with `@latest` appended to the package. So `npx create-react-flask@latest` in your case

See https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4108

There's a (somewhat involved) workaround here: https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/2329#issuecomment-873487338

Comment: Apparantly `@latest` is good to force it to update the package you're directly running, but it doesn't update any dependencies. You have to use `npx clear-npx-cache` to do that.

Answer (score 11):

Try clearing your cache by running either:

- `npm cache clean --force` (built-in)
- `npx clear-npx-cache`

After that, retry `npx create-react-flask foobar`